# My truck is stuck on top of a rock wall with a sheet of ice and snow on it, help

Tags: traction-control, ice

If you live in the frigid north of places like MN you probably slip in the winter time. I somehow got my truck (Silverado) stuck on top of a rock wall with a layer of snow on top of ice. How do I get my truck off the rock wall before it goes over the edge? The more I try to get it out, the more it slides into the wall. How do I get my truck safely out of this situation?

As the rock wall was built last year it's still under warranty, but as I have an older truck it's not.

Comment: I'm thinking this isn't really on-topic for the site, but, you need to secure the truck first on the side you are trying to get it to. If you need to back off the rock wall, secure the tail end to something which isn't moving, like a tree or another vehicle. Then use a come along to get it back far enough until you get traction, or possibly use another vehicle to pull it back for you. If your Silvy doesn't have traction, not much you can do but pray.

Answer (score 1):

You hire a breakdown wagon that can lift your vehicle and put it back on the hardtop... safest and probaly best. Dragging it may cause or at least add to any damage underneath.

Cheap probably not, but if it falls then cost of replacement plus cost of whatever else it damages on the way down...